# If statement Invalid in aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this aspx code:

```
<td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtSolarValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SolarValue") %>' />
</td>

<script runat="server">
var solarvalue = document.getElementById("ctl00_maincontent_FormView1_txtSolarValue");

if (solarvalue > 0)
{
    void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SendMail();                              
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
</script>
```

But im getting this error:

```
error CS1519: Invalid token 'if' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

I want to run the function just if the value is > 0. How could I fix it? thanks

Comment: Never do an empty catch block like that. At least log the exception. Also, it's poor practice to embed your C# code inside your ASPX page. Create a [code behind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb.aspx) to contain your C# code.

Comment: I'm confused... the top looks like javascript, but the click handler looks like c# code behind.  Are you able to do `Button2_Click` handler in javascript?

Comment: @Kritner, yes. You can do server side on customer side.@Mason, i need to use this as a work around here. How could i fix catch and If statment?

Comment: @Fresher False. Server side is on the server side. Simply placing C# code in the ASPX file does not make it execute on the client side.

Comment: @Kritner this is server-side code (attribute `runat="server"`). The confusing thing is that he does `document.getElementById()`, which is Javascript and cannot run on the server :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed JavaScript and C# code together. They don't go hand in hand. The C# executes on the server before the HTML and JS is event sent to the client (where the JavaScript executes). You should use C# to get the `solarValue` instead of JavaScript.

Also, in C# you can't have an if statement outside of a method body. You can move the if statement inside your method body to resolve the error.

```
<script runat="server">
    void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //this method should be moved to code behind
    {
        var txtSolarValue = (TextBox) FormView1.FindControl("txtSolarValue"); //this is necessary because your TextBox is nested inside a FormView
        var solarvalue = int.Parse(txtSolarValue.Text); //really need some error handling here in case it's not a valid number

        if (solarvalue > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                SendMail();                              
            }
            catch (Exception) { } //do not do empty catch blocks! Log the exception!
        }
    }
</script>
```

You should also remove the empty catch block. At least log exceptions, don't silently swallow them.

Note that modern practice is to place any C# code in a separate file called a [code behind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb.aspx). It will make the distinction between JavaScript and C# a little more distinct.

Comment: Now its much more clear to me as well. Im not C programmer so im trying to find a workaround. How could i get that value not using C but still be able to use if statement. because now i have this: error CS0103: The name 'txtSolarValue' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Fresher C is not C#. They are completely distinct languages. Anyways, your code example in your question is not complete, it doesn't show the FormView that the TextBox is inside. You should amend your question to include that. But it's probably something like `var txtSolarValue = (TextBox) FormView1.FindControl("txtSolarValue");`

Comment: almost. This worked: var solarvalue = float.Parse(((TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("txtSolarValue")).Text);